# Simulate keyboard on another web page from my web page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, simulate

I would like to display another web page within a web page... maybe using framnes, then be able to simulate mouse clicks/keyboard input randomally on this new page that is within my page.

Is this possible using asp.net/ javascript or any language. asp.net preferred

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible on client. If you are creating a desktop application then may be it could have been done like in automation, but on clint side even javascript cant create events like mouse clicks, it can only handle such events. however you can insert text in text boxes by traversing and accessing DOM in your javascript.

Its Definitely not possible from Server side in ASP.Net

Comment: Well, to be more precise, I'm pretty sure you *can* mock-fire (some) events in JavaScript, though I haven't looked into it much; however, browser security models prohibit you from doing anything within iframes pointing at another domain.  That'd be a *huge* disaster waiting to happen if it were allowed.